# pandas - select rows where the boolean filtering of a subset of columns are true

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have a dataframe 'df' from which I want to select the subset where 3 specific columns are not null.

So far I have tried to apply bool filtering

```
mask_df = df[['Empty', 'Peak', 'Full']].notnull()
```

which gives me the following result

```
    Empty   Peak    Full
0   True    False   False
1   False   False   False
2   True    True    True
3   False   False   False
4   False   False   False
... ... ... ...
2775244 True    True    True
2775245 True    True    True
2775246 False   False   False
2775247 False   False   False
2775248 False   False   False
```

Now I want to select ONLY the rows where the mask for those 3 columns is True (i.e., rows where those 3 columns have null values). If I filter the original dataframe 'df' with this mask I get the original dataframe full of null values, except those where the mask_df is "True".

I probably can do this by applying a lambda function row-wise, but I would prefer to avoid that computation if there was a simpler way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: kindly share a sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: Yes please @TiagoPedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`pandas.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df[mask_df.all(axis = 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.